# Laravel Eloquent collection attributes

Tags: php, laravel, model, attributes, eloquent

I'm developing a webapp with Laravel 5.2 but there is an issue that I can't solve.

I have a model which extends Eloquent Model but when I try to output my database table with "where", for example

```
\App\MyModel::where('id_table', 23)->first();
```

It return a collection with many informations not useful for me at this moment like 'guarded', 'keytype'... and my table's data are under 'attributes'.
Following laravel's guide I see everybody use simply where like me and then output with `$mytable->myvalue`, but this cannot work for me of course.

Here a screenshot with the collection I'm talking about:

[image]

How can I get always just attributes when I use something like `"::where()"`?

I've tried `getAttributes()` but it gives me a 500 error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to get just couple of attributes do many things. Probably first way will be the best for you:

Use [`pluck()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-pluck):

```
\App\MyModel::where('id_table', 23)->pluck('id', 'name');
```

Use [`select()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#selects):

```
\App\MyModel::select('id', 'name')->where('id_table', 23)->get();
```

Use `get()` with parameters:

```
\App\MyModel::where('id_table', 23)->get(['id', 'name']);
```

If you want to get Eloquent collection and only then build an array with just attributes, you can use [`toArray()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-toarray):

```
\App\MyModel::where('id_table', 23)->get()->toArray();
```

If you want to get some attributes to a new collection, use [`pluck()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-pluck) on collection:

```
$collection = \App\MyModel::where('id_table', 23)->get();
$names = $collection->pluck('name');
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Your method with toArray() it's more or less what I was looking for, but I've tried also select and get and they always return a collection with 'table', 'primaryKey', 'connection', 'keyType', 'perPage' (I've added an image in my question). So how can I get only attributes with, for example, the get() method?

Comment: I thought you need just some attributes. In your case `get()` will not help you, use `->get()->toArray()` to get all attributes without any additional object properties.